# How can I downsample an image while keeping the same size

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I want to know the pre-processing applied to the image on the left to get the image on the right.
Using tensor-flow or python. The goal is to apply pre-processing to the images of my data set (degradation of the image quality as in the image on the right) to study the impact on learning.
Here are my failed tests(median_filter,Maximum pooling,resize_with_the_pad,..)

[image: on the left the original image (gray level) o the right the output i want to get]

Thank you

Comment: which images? missing link

Comment: I see that someone downvoted your question. I won't do the same, but I will kindly ask you to provide more info regarding what you 're trying to achieve. P.S. the image's missing.

Comment: @AlexMetsai We don't downvote people, we downvote posts - there's a big difference.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica What I want to point is that simple downvoting without feedback in comments isn't very helpful, in my opinion, especially for new contributors.

Comment: @AlexMetsai Downvotes are not meant to be instructive to the poster (that's what the [help] is for), they're meant to be a signal to other readers as to how useful the content is perceived to be. See: [Why isn't providing feedback on downvotes mandatory, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

**Algorithm 1** (see Algorithms 2, 3, 4 below)

Here I coded manual transformations of your image to get closest result to what you want. I used Numba Python module to boost computations. Install numba through `pip install numba`, it works only for Python version <= 3.8.

Example input and output image is shown below code. Inside code you can see params `32, 8`, they control how much your image is downsampled. `32` means rounding of colors to nearest multiple of 32. And `8` control downsample level, each 8x8 square will have 1-4 colors inside of it.

Input file in my case is `dog.png` and output is `dog2.png`, change these files names to what you want.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66243434#main.py)

```
import PIL.Image, numba, math, numpy as np
@numba.njit(cache = True)
def process(a, r, s):
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    color = np.zeros((
        (a.shape[0] + s - 1) // s, (a.shape[1] + s - 1) // s
    ), dtype = np.uint8)
    for i in range(color.shape[0]):
        for j in range(color.shape[1]):
            color[i, j] = np.uint8(np.mean(a[i * s : (i + 1) * s, j * s : (j + 1) * s])) // r * r
    for i in range(s, a.shape[0] - s):
        for j in range(s, a.shape[1] - s):
            c, sk = 0, 0.
            for di, dj in [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]:
                k = (1. - math.sqrt((i - (i // s + di) * s) ** 2 + (j - (j // s + dj) * s) ** 2) / (math.sqrt(2) * s))
                sk += k
                c += color[i // s + di, j // s + dj] * k
            c /= sk
            mind, minc = 300, None
            for di, dj in [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]:
                d = abs(int(color[i // s + di, j // s + dj]) - c)
                if d < mind:
                    mind, minc = d, color[i // s + di, j // s + dj]
            b[i, j] = minc
    return b
img = PIL.Image.open('dog.png').convert('L')
img2 = PIL.Image.fromarray(process(np.array(img), 32, 8))
img2.save('dog2.png')
```

Input:

[image: img]

Output:

[image: img]

---

**Algorithm 2** (see Algorithms 3, 4 below)

Also implemented 2nd variant of algorithm, which gives a bit different results but in general with same look and feel. So up to you to decide which algorithm is better.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66243434var2#main.py)

```
import PIL.Image, numba, math, numpy as np
@numba.njit(cache = True)
def process(a, r, s):
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    color = np.zeros((
        (a.shape[0] + s - 1) // s, (a.shape[1] + s - 1) // s
    ), dtype = np.uint8)
    for i in range(color.shape[0]):
        for j in range(color.shape[1]):
            color[i, j] = np.uint8(np.mean(a[i * s : (i + 1) * s, j * s : (j + 1) * s])) // r * r
    for i in range(s, a.shape[0] - s):
        for j in range(s, a.shape[1] - s):
            l0 = [0] * 4
            for id_, (di, dj) in enumerate([(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]):
                lc = 0
                for id_2, (di2, dj2) in enumerate([(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]):
                    lc += 1 if color[i // s + di, j // s + dj] == color[i // s + di2, j // s + dj2] else 0
                l0[id_] = lc
            l1 = [0.] * 4
            for id_, (di, dj) in enumerate([(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]):
                k = l0[id_] * (1. - math.sqrt((i - (i // s + di) * s) ** 2 + (j - (j // s + dj) * s) ** 2) / (math.sqrt(2) * s))
                l1[id_] += k
            maxd, maxc = -1., None
            for id_, (di, dj) in enumerate([(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]):
                if l1[id_] > maxd:
                    maxd, maxc = l1[id_], color[i // s + di, j // s + dj]
            b[i, j] = maxc
    return b
img = PIL.Image.open('dog.png').convert('L')
img2 = PIL.Image.fromarray(process(np.array(img), 32, 8))
img2.save('dog2.png')
```

Output:

[image: img]

---

**Algorithm 3** (see Algorithm 4 below)

Later I implemented even more better algorithm, see it below. It needs more computations but looks better!

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66243434var3#main.py)

```
import PIL.Image, numba, math, numpy as np
@numba.njit(cache = True)
def process(a, r, s):
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    color = np.zeros((
        (a.shape[0] + s - 1) // s, (a.shape[1] + s - 1) // s
    ), dtype = np.uint8)
    for i in range(color.shape[0]):
        for j in range(color.shape[1]):
            color[i, j] = np.uint8(np.mean(a[i * s : (i + 1) * s, j * s : (j + 1) * s])) // r * r
    srt2 = math.sqrt(2)
    for i in range(s, a.shape[0] - s):
        for j in range(s, a.shape[1] - s):
            c, sk = 0, 0.
            for p in range(-s//2, s//2 + 1):
                for q in range(-s//2, s//2 + 1):
                    k = (1. - math.sqrt(p ** 2 + q ** 2) / (s * srt2 / 2))
                    sk += k
                    c += a[i + p, j + q] * k
            c /= sk
            mind, minc = 300, None
            for di, dj in [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]:
                d = abs(int(color[i // s + di, j // s + dj]) - c)
                if d < mind:
                    mind, minc = d, color[i // s + di, j // s + dj]
            b[i, j] = minc
    return b
img = PIL.Image.open('dog.png').convert('L')
img2 = PIL.Image.fromarray(process(np.array(img), 32, 8))
img2.save('dog2.png')
```

Output:

[image: img]

---

**Algorithm 4**

This algorithm is a much smoother variant of Algorithm 3, uses similar logic and same amount of computation but does more smoothing.

To me this 4th algorithm looks the best!

To remind you - in code `32, 8` params control look and feel of result. 32 here is rounding factor of colors, all colors are rounded to multiple of 32. 8 is pixel radius of computing mean for each point, it means that each pixel color is computed as weighted mean of colors of all pixels in radius 8, weight for each pixel is back-proportional to [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) distance to that pixel.

Also second param `8` signifies amount of computation needed, the bigger it is the more computation for each pixel is done, the less it is the faster is algorithm.

Basically my Algorithm 4 does 2D convolution with fixed kernel, so if wanted it can be converted easily to TensorFlow. But because of Numba this algorithm is already very fast, close to speed of C++ implementation. The only reason for using TensorFlow is if you want to incorporate all CPU cores or you have a GPU. Even multi-core version can be easily done using Python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module and my Numba-based algorithm.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66243434var4#main.py)

```
import PIL.Image, numba, math, numpy as np
@numba.njit(cache = True)
def process(a, r, s):
    b, ks = np.zeros_like(a), np.zeros((2 * s + 1, 2 * s + 1), dtype = np.float64)
    for p in range(-s, s + 1):
        for q in range(-s, s + 1):
            ks[p + s, q + s] = (1. - min(s, math.sqrt(p ** 2 + q ** 2)) / s)
    ks /= np.sum(ks)
    for i in range(s, a.shape[0] - s):
        for j in range(s, a.shape[1] - s):
            c = 0
            for p in range(-s, s + 1):
                for q in range(-s, s + 1):
                    c += a[i + p, j + q] * ks[p + s, q + s]
            b[i, j] = round(c) // r * r
    return b
img = PIL.Image.open('dog.png').convert('L')
img2 = PIL.Image.fromarray(process(np.array(img), 32, 8))
img2.save('dog2.png')
```

Output:

[image: img]

---

**Algorithm 4 Colored**

Algorithm 4 can be easily adopted to colored image with extra small modifications (2D-convolution filter is applied separately to 3 channels):

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66243434var5#main.py)

```
import PIL.Image, numba, math, numpy as np
@numba.njit(cache = True)
def process(a, r, s):
    b, ks = np.zeros_like(a), np.zeros((2 * s + 1, 2 * s + 1), dtype = np.float64)
    for p in range(-s, s + 1):
        for q in range(-s, s + 1):
            ks[p + s, q + s] = (1. - min(s, math.sqrt(p ** 2 + q ** 2)) / s)
    ks /= np.sum(ks)
    for ch in range(a.shape[2]):
        for i in range(s, a.shape[0] - s):
            for j in range(s, a.shape[1] - s):
                c = 0
                for p in range(-s, s + 1):
                    for q in range(-s, s + 1):
                        c += a[i + p, j + q, ch] * ks[p + s, q + s]
                b[i, j, ch] = round(c) // r * r
    return b
img = PIL.Image.open('cat.jpg')
img2 = PIL.Image.fromarray(process(np.array(img), 32, 8))
img2.save('cat2.png')
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You chose the TF, so it's probably for detection/classification needs.
If you use downsampling for preprocessing, it's better to preprocess you images in advance, before training/inferring the model.
But if downsampling is a stage of your model, you can use one of:

```
# Generates the different levels of the pyramid (downsampling).
tfg.image.pyramid.downsample
```

or

```
# Will generate all images of the same size, so it will be easier to apply other layers
resized_images = tf.image.resize_images(images, (224, 224))
```